# Java stream access the methods of List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following snippet

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int res = list.stream()
    .filter(e-> list.indexOf(e) ==  list.lastIndexOf(e))
    .findFirst()
    .get();
// here I'm creating stream on list, and to access methods of list itself I'm using a reference
```

But If I am using `Arrays.asList` or `Arrays.stream` to create a stream How can I access these methods.
I know I can First convert the Arrays to Collection. But I want a more efficient way to do this.

Am I missing something about streams? or Something. Also, suggest to me about the `list.stream` is there any way to improve?

Comment: @AlexRudenko, seems the code returns first non-repeating number.

Comment: I want help about the using this methods in Arrays.asList or my question is rather about the direstly using those methods in list stream.

Comment: Yeah the code is about to find non repeating element in list. But see this my problem is I am using list object twice in the stream. So my question how can use these list methods such as indexOf directly within list.stream

Comment: I'm confused, as your code is not using methods from Arrays.  If you need to get a stream from array (not from a list), you can do this with like this: `int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4}; Arrays.stream(arr)`.  You can also get stream like this: `Arrays.asList(1,2, 3, 4).stream()`

Comment: If you mean using method reference like `list::indexOf` in `filter`, the answer in this case is `no`.

Comment: If I want to use methods of list(indexof) on Arrays , what should I do ? @AlexRudenko. I know I cannot use method ref cause this methods are not static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize discussion in comments, there could be a way to work with array, but of course without using List methods:

```
public class Test {

    private int[] array; // no setter

    public int findNonRepeating(int... arr) {
        this.array = arr;
        return Arrays.stream(array).filter(this::isNonRepeating).findFirst().orElse(-1);
    }

    private boolean isNonRepeating(int a) {
        int fix = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                           .filter(i -> array[i] == a)
                           .findFirst().orElse(-1);
        int lix = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                           .map(i -> array.length - i - 1)
                           .filter(i -> array[i] == a)
                           .findFirst().orElse(-1);
        return fix == lix && fix != -1;
    }
}
```

Though, more preferable way to implement this seems to be this:

```
public int findFirstNonRepeating(int...arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr)
                 .boxed()
                 .collect(
                     Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                 .entrySet().stream()
                 .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
                 .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey())
                 .findFirst().orElse(-1);
}
```

***update***

In order to reuse `List` functionality as much as possible, you may extend `ArrayList` and provide predicate method:

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    public static <T> MyList<T> of(Collection<? extends T> collection) {
        return new MyList<>(collection);
    }
    
    public MyList() { super(); }
    public MyList(int initialCapacity) { super(initialCapacity); }
    public MyList(Collection<? extends T> collection) { super(collection); }

    public boolean isNonRepeating(T x) {
        int fx = this.indexOf(x);
        return fx > -1 && fx == this.lastIndexOf(x);
    }
    
    public T findFirstNonRepeating() {
        return stream()
                .filter(this::isNonRepeating)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> 
                    new NoSuchElementException("This list does not contain non-repeating elements")
                );
    }
}


int x = MyList.of(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 1)).findFirstNonRepeating().intValue();
// x = 2
```

Comment: I got your point for efficiency and more preferable way to solve this problem. But what I am asking is consider any x method from List , I'm creating  a stream from that List and using the this method x in filter as above. is there any way to use this method without explicitly calling using List